# Accessing docker webapp (on a remote server) from my browser

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, web-applications, docker-network

I created a python flask-webapp that runs within a docker container (flask and mysql).

Now I got ssh-access to a remote-server. I would like to run this application on the server and I want to access it now from my host.

My steps taken:

- I connected to the remote-server `ssh user@<some-ip>` and transferred the application to the remote-server
- I built it and ran the `docker-compose up -d` so that it runs in the background

A snippet after running `docker ps -a`:

```
IMAGE       STATUS  PORTS
flask-app   up      0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, :::9000->9000/tcp
mysql       up      3306/tcp, 33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3308->3308/tcp, :::3308->3308/tcp
```

Now my question is which further steps do I have to take to reach the remote server's application from my host browser now?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: You either have to allow port 9000 through the server's firewall, or use ssh tunneling to reach 9000 behind the firewall.  Note that if 9000 is open to all IPs in the firewall, your service will be publicly accessible.  If you want to keep access private, ssh tunnel is way to go.  If you want to make service publicly accessible, open the firewall.

Comment: @erik258 thank you for your response! Could you elaborate on the steps needed to achieve either of both?

Comment: the firewall would depend on server and/or hosting.  https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example#local-forwarding describes local forwarding .  From what you've provided sounds like it would be something like `ssh -f -L 9000:localhost:9000 user@some-ip` and then you can connect to `localhost:9000` on your end and `ssh` will forward the traffic to `localhost:9000` on the remote end.

Comment: @erik258 thank you. I entered now the ``ssh -L 9000:localhost:9000 user@some-ip`` and I login. But when I want to connect from my local browser ``localhost:9000`` I get nothing back. Thanks for any further help!